# jquery -Yii fetch value of Selected radio

Tags: jquery, radiobuttonlist

```
<div class="form-group field-userform-custtype required">
<label class="control-label" for="custtype1">Custtype</label>
<input type="hidden" name="UserForm[custtype]" value="">
<div id="custtype1" class="flip">           
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="UserForm[custtype]" value="1"> B2C</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="UserForm[custtype]" value="2"> B2B</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="UserForm[custtype]" value="3"> Both</label></div>
<div class="help-block"></div>

</div>
```

Here I want to extract value of selected radio. I tried getting value by:

```
$('input:radio[name=UserForm[custtype]]:checked').val()
```

but no luck.

**Required output : 1 or 2 or 3 based on the selection.**

Please help me on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly was wrong with what you tried?  What output or error did you get and what did you expect?

Comment: sir question updated. I need value 1 or 2 or 3 based on the selected radio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks fine. You have just forget the quotes surrounding the name. It should be like this:

```
$('input:radio[name="UserForm[custtype]"]:checked').val()
```

Hope it's useful!

Comment: Thank you so much, I am great fool. :)

Comment: Thank's bro, it helped me a lot!